# name of class is not defined and iterating values within a class

Tags: python, class, loops, oop

I'm just starting to use classes in python and am having a couple issues.

My first class and it's constructor just for reference for spot I'm having issues with:

```
class Course:
    def __init__(self, number, credit,grade):
        self.number = str(number)
        self.credit= int(credit)
        self.grade= str(grade)
```

Here's where I'm having issues. When I run it, it comes up and tells me that " names "Course" is not defined". Why would that be? Also I'm trying to initially create an empty list in `__init__` to add to later. In my `__str__` function I'm trying to iterate through the values I have in Course  and create a string out representation in the format of  ( example of out put):

```
Transcript:
   English: credit 4, grade A
   Math:credit 3, grade C
```

What I've been working with so far for my second class:

```
class Transcript:

    courses = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.courses = Course()


    def __str__(self):

        s = ""
        i = 0
        while (i < 10):
            s += self.courses[i].__str__()  
        return s


    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

I feel it's probably obvious what I should be doing, but I'm very iffy on OOP since I just started learning it this week.

Oops! Looks like a little typo I made was causing the first error, but now I'm not understanding my current error where it says "TypeError: **init** missing 3 required positional arguments : "number", "class ", "grade". I didn't think I'd need to add those args into it while doing x = classname() . What is causing this?

Comment: The name of your class is `Course` not `Courses`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

You have to override __str__ method  in your `Course`,

in your `Transcript` class, use an instance list variable `courses` other than the previous class instance `courses`, creates 2 `Course` instances and inserts them into `courses`

to create a `Course` instance, it should be like this: `Course("English", 4, "A")`

cat course.py

```
class Course:
    def __init__(self, number, credit,grade):
        self.number = str(number)
        self.credit= int(credit)
        self.grade= str(grade)

    def __str__(self):
        """override __str__, display the information in the way you prefer"""
        return "{0}: credit {1}, grade {2}".format(self.number, self.credit, self.grade)
```

$cat transcript.py

```
from course import Course

class Transcript:

    def __init__(self):
        self.courses = list()  # creates an instance varialbe courses
        self.courses.append(Course("English", 4, "A"))  # appends english course
        self.courses.append(Course("Math", 3, "C"))  # appends math course

    def __str__(self):
       """ overrides __str__, iterates your courses list and add all course string into a list,
           finally converts the list into a string with newline character as the delimiter
       """
       tmp_list = list()
       for c in self.courses:
           tmp_list.append(str(c))
       return "\n".join(tmp_list)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

$cat test.py

```
from transcript import Transcript

print(Transcript())
```

$python test.py

```
English: credit 4, grade A
Math: credit 3, grade C
```

**Original Answer:**

2 things you need to fix:

1)You have a typo, it is Course not Courses

2)the list `courses` you declared in Transcript is a class instance, and you create a instance variable has the same name `courses` and then you use your instance variable as a list `self.courses[i].__str__()` which will generate error

Comment: alright, thanks for the tips. I changed the names to different things and I'm still getting the error I edited in at the end of my original post above.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the init method of your Course class is taking 3 arguments namely number,grade,credit. So when you are trying to create a instance of this class it is needed for you to pass all these three arguments while creating a instance of this class.
So Try Creating the instance by passing the arguments.

Hope this will solve your Problem.

Thank You